# How to change the date format from dd-mon-yyyy to mmddyyyy in plsql??

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, format

Changed date should be in Date data type only. I dont want to convert it to varchar by using to_char function. I want the changed format to be in date only.

Comment: date type is just date type, either when you stored it in the database or in your application level; there isn't date type in `dd-mon-yyyy` format and date type in `mmddyyyy` format. What you want is to format its string representation when you want to display it to the user.

Comment: What do you mean with "in PL/SQL"? PL/SQL does not "display" anything because it only runs on the server when you run your stored procedure. Please post the code of your stored procedure.

Comment: see am having a date which  is in 25-jun-2009 (say) format and i want to convert it to 06252009(mmddyyyy)...to_char function can do this but it would will become varchar which i dont want.

Comment: You don't understand the difference between a data type and the presentation (date format). Please meditate on @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 comment until you see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY';
```

This will change the default date format in the current session.